# HTML checkbox passing all values insted of selected

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a form which pass values to django view.
In the form there is a dynamically generated table with a checkbox.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, 'no')"></th>
            <th>Order Id</th>
            <th>Channel</th>
            <th>Dispatch By Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Products</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for oid,oiid,dbd,stts,tp,sku,qty,chnl in new_orders %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="{{oid}}"></td>
            <td>
                <div><a class="btn-link" href="#">{{oid}}</a></div>
                <div><input name="oiid" style="display:none" value="{{oiid}}">{{oiid}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>{{chnl}}<input name="channel" style="display:none" value="{{chnl}}"></td>
            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{dbd}}</span></td>
            <td>{{tp}}</td>
            <td>{{stts}}</td>
            <td>
                <div>{{sku}}</div>
                <div>Quantity: {{qty}}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am passing 3 values back to my view. `oid, oiid, chnl`.
The problem is if I select some elements instead of all, then the value of all  `oid` is passed for those elements but the for `oiid` and `chnl` all the value are passed.

My Javascript:

```
function toggle(source, text) {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(text);
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
```

How to pass only those values which are selected for all three variables?

Comment: So ... Does my answer have helped you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must type all your inputs with `type="checkbox"` and `name="YOURCHECKBOXNAME[]"`.

`YOURCHECKBOXNAME` should be the same.

When you put `[]` in a HTML input, the form will send to PHP an array.

Comment: Sorry I was out for some work..Should i pass value like this:  <td><input type="checkbox" name="no[]" value="{{oid}}"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="no[]" value="{{oiid}}"></td>

Comment: Yes. You will receive an array when you send the form using POST.

Comment: If you need more examples or help, tell me. But remember I don't speak very well english. I'm a french student so ... :)